# How can I use PowerShell's Invoke-Sqlcmd with Azure Active Directory's Multi Factor Authentication (MFA)?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

I want a user that runs a PowerShell script that calls Invoke-Sqlcmd to have to provide their Azure Active Directory username, password and MFA response for authentication to the configured Azure SQL Database. I've found surprisingly little information on this topic. I tried omitting -Username and -Password but receive this error:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd : Windows logins are not supported in this version of SQL Server.
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, SSMS and SqlPackage.exe are the only tools currently enabled for MFA through Active Directory Universal Authentication. For more details, please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-ssms-mfa-authentication#universal-authentication-limitations-for-sql-database-and-sql-data-warehouse)

If you have any idea or suggestion about Azure SQL database, you can submit them from [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database).

Answer (score 0):

Got this response from Azure support, I asked the same question there.

> Currently SQLCMD and BCP utilities are the only supported utilities
>   for interactive authentication. Invoke-SQLCMD is not one of the
>   supported utilities yet.

:(

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, they support this feature now. "The new BCP supports Azure AD authentication, including Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA) support for SQL Database and SQL Data Warehouse."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility